# ngForTrackBy Angular2 Docs example

Tags: angular

I'm reading through [Angular2 Basics docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngFor) and I've come across this gif explaining the use of ngForTrackBy. How did the author check if the DOM elements changed?

[image]

I cannot reproduce this example on my own, given my limited experience with Angular.

Comment: The example source is here: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/template-syntax/ts/plnkr.html  in app/app.component.ts  Have a look at how it was implemented.

Comment: link is broken.